# How do i add parameter passing to this

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I need to add parameter passing to this code but don't know how, i tried a few different things but it just broke the code everytime

[image: My code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - do not post PICTURES of code, post CODE

Comment: Maybe one of these will help: [`[javascript] pass argument to event handler`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+pass+argument+to+event+handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass parameters to your `calc` function, you can just create an anonymous function from the click event, add some code to gather your parameters to pass in and then call the `calc` function like so:

```
document.getElementById("currencybtn").addEventListener('click', function () {
  let myParameter = 10;
  calc(myParameter);
});
```

And then in your `calc` function, you can name that parameter anything you'd like.  It doesn't have to be named `myParameter` because your `calc` function will use the first variable you pass to it with the first variable you put inside of the parenthesis when you call your `calc` function:

```
function calc(param1) {
//param1 is myParameter from above
//JavaScript pulls in variables based on the order they are received
return param1 + 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the arguments from the target attribute of the event, somehing like this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', calc, false);
button.randomParam = 'just a random parameter';

function calc(e)
{
  window.alert(e.currentTarget.randomParam);
}
```

```html
<button class="input">click me</button>
```